# Debian Start Qt GUI application with no desktop

Tags: linux, qt, debian, autostart

I have Debian 2.6 running on a SBC that I plan on using in an embedded setup. What I need to do is configure it so that linux will start up and run just my Qt GUI application. Do I need a window manager to do this or can I just do it with X11. Also because it is going to be for an embedded system I do not want to load any desktop manager. Any info on how this can be done would be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can do this without a window manager.

**first**: You need to boot into a non X session, init level 1 or 3.

**second**: You need to start the X server, in a basic mode by just calling X or xinit.

**third**: Start your app. You may need to take a little more control over where your app is positioned on the screen and its dimensions in your code, as you will not have a window manager to help with this.

**alternatively**: you can launch one of the more basic window managers to see how they play with your system. Motif Window Manager (mwm) and Tab Window Manager (twm)

**Note**: While working without a window manager, you may get into a state where you cannot do some very basic operations (ex: close a window, move a window, resize a window). You may find that you cannot survive without at least some of the more basic window management functions. Until you close the loop on this, remember, Ctrl + Alt + Backspace will kill the XServer.

Comment: OK, I got the auto login working and I can start X but I'm having troubles getting applications to launch once X starts... I have tried editing ~/.xsession to include exec xterm & (or similar app) but it never loads... any ideas?

Comment: try using xinit first, it will give you an xterm session. Another thing to check is the environment variable DISPLAY

Answer (score 4):

If you want to start your app just with X11, you need do:

1. copy file /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc to ~/.xinitrc
2. write all you want to run to it
3. run command startx

It worked for me and I hope it will help you