# I need to show only a window after login (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, window, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I need to load a program after login, without loading the desktop. only showing the program I made.
I need it on ubuntu

Comment: I've added the kiosk & kiosk-mode tags to your post. That would also be the most rewarding search terms to use for your problem.

Comment: Looking through similar tagged questions, this answer could help you meet your criteria: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3497092/53444

Comment: This looks like it is more of a configuration of Ubuntu issue that might be better served at SU or AskUbuntu (seeing this is referring to Ubuntu). Maybe this should be migrated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/

Or, this:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS

If touchscreen, I'd give xmonad a shot to ensure fullscreen, else you  may get odd borders with no window manager. Matchbox good too.